# How to export sonar report with all description in csv?

Tags: csv, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

i exported project report in CSV format. But it contains only numbers like Major issues 850, Minor issues 450 & etc; But i need to generate detail description of those Major and Minor issues in CSV format like, i need to export full description where the major issue??, whether it is closed what is new issue like in the issue table... Please help me to do this

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the interface?

Comment: Nothing wrong i need CSV report which includes all the detailed description but in normal CSV export plugin it comes only number of issues but in sonar console it shows all the details, like issues are closed or not , which line contains issue like that... I need like that report in CSV format please help me to get that description...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rules Search web service](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/rules/search) to get rule descriptions.

Comment: Actually i am using sonar 3.7.4, Is there any option available for this version to export the report???

Comment: Uhm... upgrade? Seriously, 3.7.4 is almost 3 years old at this point.